# ModelState.AddModelError - How can I makeup the Resource error string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a ASP.NET MVC5 project where I do some input validation over more then 1 field.
When an error is found I add an error to the model via :

```
ModelState.AddModelError("field", Resource.ErrorMessage);
```

The ErrorMessage in the resource file (I have several for different languages) looks like this :
"{0} should be {1}"

How should I code the AddModelError to fill {0} and {1} in the ErrorMessage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String.Format :

```
string errorMessage = String.Format(Resource.ErrorMessage,  "X",  "Y" ); 
ModelState.AddModelError("field", errorMessage );
```